# По нажатию на блок div перейти в метод контроллера

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Имеется вот такая часть view:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 imgEvents" style="background-image:url(../../Content/additional/formusic2.jpg); background-size:100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 335px; ">
 <h4 style="color:#ffffff;"><b>@ev.Title</b></h4>
 <h5 style="color:#ffffff;">@ev.Discription</h5>
@Html.ActionLink("DETAILS »", "EventDetails", "EventDetails", new { eventId = ev.Id }, null) 
</div>
```

сейчас у меня в блоке div есть кнопка для перехода к нужному мне месту, я хотел бы сделать так чтобы можно было кликать по всему блоку (т.к блок это картинка)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Нужно исправить блок div на button и обрабатывать действие onclick. Eсли не нравятся эффекты кнопки, то изменить их с помощью css.

```
<button onclick="@Url.Action("EventDetails", "EventDetails", new {Id = ev.Id}, null)">
    <h4 style="color:#ffffff;"><b>@ev.Title</b></h4>
    <h5 style="color:#ffffff;">@ev.Discription</h5>
</botton>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DETAILS", "EventDetails", new { eventId = ev.Id })">
    <div>
        <h4 style="color:#ffffff;"><b>@ev.Title</b></h4>
        <h5 style="color:#ffffff;">@ev.Discription</h5>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: данный метод не работает